# Print data only in form on-click Print button AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form, ng-controller

I have multiple add-remove input field rows in my form. This is nothing but a report. There is a print button and I want to print only data entered in form in structured manner. Similar like table,column,rows and text but not buttons or input box borders. I tried this for print button

```
javascript:window.print()
```

And created classes using

```
{
  display: none;
  border: none;
}
```

Wanted to know how to write function where i can collect data and get print view in structured manner on-click Print button.

This is code i am working on

[See Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E7UuiU9wwmRydBrlL1O1?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a print style sheet. There are a number of articles on the web that describe how to create this, but in essence it is a separate stylesheet that allows you to create a separate style for printing, thereby you can hide items, change font sizes, remove borders etc when the html page is printed. I think this might help you solve your problem. A search result here: [tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/)